# How do I tell Rails how to correctly capitalize an acronym?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a field called `sui` in one of my models.  It stands for "Standard User Identifier."  When there are validation errors on the field, Rails prints "Sui is required" or "Sui is already taken."

How can I tell Rails that `'sui'.titleize` is "SUI"?  I looked at `Inflector.human`, but that isn't quite right.

Answer (score 7):

In such cases I use [custom_err_msg](http://rubyforge.org/projects/custom-err-msg/) plugin. As it is installed you can give custom error messages like this:

```
validates_presence_of :sui, :message => '^SUI is required'
```

When you put ^ at the begining then Rails don't put field name.

EDIT:
There is another plugin [i18n_label](http://github.com/iain/i18n_label/tree/master) used for translations, but with it you can in very simple way replace a name of your field with something nicer (on plugin page there is an example). It will substitute name in:

```
<%= f.label :sui %>
YourModel.human_attribute_name "sui"
```

and in error messages.

Comment: FANTASTIC tip!  Is there a way to put the value that's causing problems into the message?  "#{sui} is taken" won't work since it gets eval'd at the wrong time.

Comment: I'm hoping someone has a suggestion that works for more than just error messages, but I do like the plugin.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by configuring [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html), which provides the [titleize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-titleize) method. Simply define your own [inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) in an initializer.

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'SUI'
end
```

Restart your app to pick up the change. Now `titleize` knows how to handle "SUI". Fire up a Rails console to check it out:

```
> "sui".titleize
=> "SUI"
```

See the linked docs for more cool stuff you can do with inflections.